# 'Sort By' changes dashboard in metadata

Tags: metadata, dashboard, sort

I have a dashboard with unchecked 'Use chart settings from report'.
I changed the field in Sort By options and can't find these changes in Dachbord metadata. 
[image]

Where can I find 'Sort By' changes in metadata?

Comment: aren't these in [DashboardComponentFilter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_dashboard.htm?search_text=dashboard) ?